# Is it possible to use a non-HTTPS URL as a Web Callback URL for a web app connected to Square?

Tags: ios, web-applications, square-connect

I am developing a POS system as a web application which will run on a browser which is not Safari (Star WebPRNT Browser). The web callback URL I wish to use is the iOS App URL Scheme for the Star WebPRNT Browser but the Application Dashboard on the Square Developer site will only let me use a HTTPS URL. I also have the problem of the Square POS app redirecting to the callback URL immediately after opening so I can't make a payment (the callback URL in this case is https://www.example.com/ as it is a HTTPS URL).

```
var dataParameter = {
        "amount_money": {
            "amount" : "500",
            "currency_code" : "USD"
        },
        "callback_url" : "https://www.example.com",
        "client_id" : "My application ID in actual code",
        "version": "1.3",
        "options" : {
            "supported_tender_types" : ["CREDIT_CARD"]
        }
    };
    window.location.assign("square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter)));
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error when you're unable to take a payment?

Also, have you registered the callback URL at connect.squareup.com/apps for your Application ID?

Comment: I registered the callback URL as https://www.example.com in connect.squareup.com/apps because it won't let me use a non-HTTPS URL. The app also does not display the payment as it displays £0.00 when it is opened.

Comment: Is your account a UK account? it looks like the data being passed specifies USD.  Try GBP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but currently we do not support web callback URL schemes other than HTTPS.  Also, iOS does not allow apps other than Safari to serve (http|s) requests.

However, we're currently looking at adding a feature to the Square POS iOS app that will redirect back to Star Webprnt or AirWatch if the request originated from one of those apps.

The ability to do this, however, hinges on whether the Star WebPRNT iOS app supports app switching via a custom URL scheme.

UPDATE: We've reached out to the Star Micronics integration team, and the Star WebPRNT app does not support app switching, though it may in the future.

They do, however, have another app called PassPRNT, which does support app switching.  See [here](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx) for the documentation under PassPRNT > iOS.

With PassPRNT, the flow would look like:

1. Open your POS web app in Safari
2. Send the request to Square POS with a callback to your https URL.
3. When your POS app receives the callback, redirect to PassPRNT with the desired URL.
4. Example PassPRNT iOS URL: **starpassprnt://v1/print/nopreview?html=PrintingDataInHTML&size=3&drawer=ahead&back=https://myposapp.com/path-to-return-to-after-printing**

Comment: How long do you think it will be until the feature that redirects back to Star WebPRNT will be added?

Comment: Also, do you know any other apps and/or card readers which provide this feature?